# time_ago_in_words is cut short

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I face a minor problem in Chapter 10 of the Rails Tutorial. My spec tests all pass but the list of the user microposts look a bit different than shown in the tutorial - namely, the time stamp is displayed without the "ago" word - so "Posted 4 days ago" becomes "Posted 4 days":
[image]

I think I followed all instructions correctly. Here is the code for the micropost partial:

```
<li>
<span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
<span class="timestamp">
Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %>
</span>
</li>
```

And here is the stylesheet:

```
/* microposts */

.microposts {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 10px 0 0 0;

 li {
 padding: 10px 0;
 border-top: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
 }
}

.content {
display: block;
}

.timestamp {
color: $grayLight;
}

.gravatar {
float: left;
margin-right: 10px;
}

aside {
 textarea {
 height: 100px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at [the api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`time_ago_in_words`** will not add **`ago`** word.You should be adding it maually.

This should work.

```
<li>
<span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
<span class="timestamp">
Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago. #here
</span>
</li>
```